# What is the difference between 回答 and 答复?

Tags: word-choice, difference

According to 现代汉语词典:

- 答复

> 回答问题或要求
>
> 对问题或要求做出的回答

- 回答

> 对提出的问题、要求给予解答或表示意见
>
> 对提出的问题、要求所作出的答复

For me both seem to be practically the same. One uses the other in its explanation.

At least for me, it feels that 回答 is a more general word while 答复 is more formal, and usually used when it involves someone superior. But I'm not sure if this is correct.

So I wonder if there is any difference between them, on its usage as verb.

Comment: users suggest studying the examples supplied by comprehensive dictionaries like bkrs

Comment: per comment #1: **回答** 1) [answer; reply; response]
(2) 口头或书面的答复; 对问题、 呼唤、 呼吁或号召的答复; 对意见、 争论或反对意见的答辩; 回信
对正当问题的诚恳回答
(3) 以口头或书面答复
我向你提问时, 请回答我answer; reply; response:
回答问题 answer a question
我考虑成熟后再给你回答。 I'll let you have an answer after mature consideration.
他们必须得到一个要么是要么非的明确回答。 They must have a definite reply， yes or no.
answer; reply
请回答我的问题。 Please answer my question.

 **答案** [answer; **solution** ; key] 对提出的问题所做的解答
练习的答案 问题的解答。
如：「请给我一个正确的答案。」answer; solution;  
练习的答案 key to an exercise
找到问题的答案 find a solution to the problem
那只有一个答案。 There is only one answer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

回答: just to answer;

答复: answer with a reply, usually in the form of writing, like a letter, an email, and etc. It connotes that to answer with some sort of attachment, which suggests the answer is a bit formal in some degree.

Answer (score 2):

The two terms are very similar. The difference is how the terms are constructed:  答复 is more like "to reply" (v) or "a reply" (n); while 回答 is more like "to answer" (v) or "an answer" (n)

> 答(answer/ reply) 复(reply/return)
>
> 答复 = 'answer with a reply' or 'return with an answer'  (to someone's question or request)
>
> or simply "**reply**" /answer

~

> 回(return)答 (answer/ reply)
>
> 回答 = return with an answer/reply (to someone's question or request)
>
> or simply "**answer**" / "reply"

~

> 回(return) 复 (reply)
>
> 回复 = return with an reply (to someone's question or request)
>
> or simply "**reply**"